# flot jquery is it possible to draw this kind of chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I used to draw this kind of chart (one vertical axis, one horizantal axis):

[image]

Now i have been asked to do this kind of chart:
[image]

as you see, the problem with the ordered chart that it contains (two vertical axis, one horizantal axis).

#### My question

does flot or any other jquery library able to do that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the flot example here on [multiple axis](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-multiple/index.html).  Minimal example:

```
$.plot("#placeholder", [
    { data: d1 },
    { data: d2, yaxis: 2 } // set second series to use second axis
], {
    yaxes: [ { 
            min: 0 // options for first axis
        }, {
            alignTicksWithAxis: 1 // options for second axis, put it on right
            position: "right"
        } ],
});
```

Two mix a bar and line chart set that in each's series object:

```
    $.plot("#placeholder", [{
        data: d1,
        lines: { show: true }
    }, {
        data: d2,
        bars: { show: true }
    }]);
```

Putting these together, here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/En7DL737Ued6ZjByIZSb?p=preview):

[image]